# Prediction output for kriging in QGIS not working

Tags: gis, interpolation, qgis, kriging

I am fairly new to QGIS and am trying to use the kriging function. For context, I have a dataset for average traffic in Scotland, with traffic being counted at specific count points along all of the roads. I want to use the kriging function to smooth out the average traffic between these count points, so I can get an average daily traffic amount for different sections of road.

I have managed to create an output, but it doesn't show up on my map and I'm not sure why. I have checked that everything has the same CRS and have tried simplifying the dataset but it hasn't worked. It also keeps coming up with this error at the end of the output:

````
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/Katie PC/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_a184e5e01a4f4b67a4ed9598de7b59d2/394a792b571d446285157cf1b1d0dd08/VARIANCE.sdat</li><li>C:/Users/Katie PC/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_a184e5e01a4f4b67a4ed9598de7b59d2/b8eaefc5170347bcb4fca4f4a6b2038f/PREDICTION.sdat</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.```

Any help would be much appreciated.
````

Comment: Did you do this? `You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm`

Comment: You might also have better luck here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/